# Is Children of a Sayyida mother still count as direct descendant of prophet muhammad S.A.W?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, sunni, sayyid

Assalamualaikum,

I have a question if a Children of a Sayyida mother with a non syed father is called mirza. Does mirza still count as direct descendant of prophet muhammad S.A.W (ahlul bait?) or is it only applied to Sayyid and syarif?

Comment: Or is it only counted from the father side?

Comment: If only the father site would count logically there would be no Sayyid left at all as the prophet () only had daughters who may have given birth as his sons died before even reaching the age marriage. But that also depends on the interpretation of who is Sayyid. In my understanding it can only be the offspring of the prophet () himself.